# Use Wamp without having to use projects

Tags: wamp, lamp, mamp

So, I love Wamp. It's great for development. The only downside is that in wamp, I have to code everything to use "localhost/projectname/" as a base, but on my actual site, everything has the base of just "/".

Is there a way to use wamp where it treats localhost has your website url?

Comment: could you be more precise ? where's your project standing on your file system ? which o.s. do you use ?

Comment: Windows 7.  

My development site is in C:/wamp/www/projectname

My problem is that, for example, in my dev. site, if I want to link to a certain page, I have to type "/projectname/contact", but the dev site should just be "/contact".

Basically, WAMP acts as if my "url" is "localhost/projectname", when I want it to be just "localhost".  I hope that makes more sense

Comment: i use xampp. I can actually put my files under the root folder, so you can access it via localhost/, no need a subfolder for it. I think you can do that same thing. No need to have a sub folder

Comment: @Shadow_boi that's not his request, I'm not an administrator but as far as I'm concerned about the stack overflow's readability, please answer only if you have an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here's how I'm doing :

1. I'm editing my *httpd.conf* file and append a **virtual host** at
   the bottom of it (in the dedicated lines) each time I want to add a
   new local website :

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/fake"
       ServerName fakesite
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. And I tell windows to point the local host address (127.0.0.1) from
   the hostname that I defined (**fakesite** in the example):

> I'm using windows and I just edit the following file :
>   `X:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and append a new line as
>   follow : `127.0.0.1     fakesite`

*note* : you'll need to restart wamp after edition config files.

This way and if everything went right you'll just need to type `fakesite/xxx` to reach the following physical folder : `c:/wamp/www/fake/xxx`

Comment: Then what do you type into the url to get to it?

Comment: @user821843 read the last line : `http://fakesite/xxx` *fakesite* is the new hostname (replacing `http://localhost/fake` if not using VirtualHost) and therefore `c:/wamp/www/fake` becomes the document_root of your website instead of `c:/wamp/www`

Comment: Sorry. It's late. My reading isn't the best right now. Thank you for all the help

Comment: @Shadow_boi no `http://fakesite/` is what you need to type `fakesite` is the server name

Comment: So, I did all this, and it works if I go to fakesite.com, but if i try to go to any subpages, like fakesite.com/contact, it gives me an internal server error

Comment: This new problem has something to do with my htaccess file I think. If I go to fakesite.com/index.php/contact, it works

Comment: @user821843 ok glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to set up a real server, use apache vhosts to set a fake domain and edit your windows hosts file to point to your local server?

When I do that, I set up samba shares so I can still use Windows to edit my files, then hit "save" in the editor and just refresh the browser. Works like a charm.